# Unwanted slash on creating regex

Tags: javascript, regex

By [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/494035/4344976) I want to use a variable in regex but it creates an extra `/` in the output:

```
var counter = 0,
    replace = "/\$" + counter;
    regex = new RegExp(replace);
    console.log(regex);
```

The output is `/\/$0/` while I expected `/\$0/`, would you tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: So, why add `/` to the `replace` variable in the first place? You seem to want `replace = "\\$" + counter;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a `/` to your regular expression string before it's generated (generation adds `/`), and you need to escape the backslash:

```js
var counter = 0;
var replace = "\\$" + counter;
var regex = new RegExp(replace);
console.log(regex);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/` at the front is being escaped because `/` characters must be escaped in regular expressions delimited by `/` (which is how the console expresses your regex when you log it).

The `\` before the `$` is lost because `\` is an escape character *in JavaScript strings* as well as in regular expressions. Log `replace` to see that the `\$` is parsed as `$`. You need to escape the `\` itself if you want it to survive into the regular expression.